# How to extract a cookie from a superagent response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, superagent

I'm using Superagent's `agent()` method to enable cookies when making HTTP requests. This is my code:

```
const agent = request.agent();
const login = await agent
    .post("http://localhost:3000/login")
    .field("email", "john@doe.com")
    .field("password", "test");

console.log("result is: ", login);
```

All is well, I can see in the dump that the `Cookie` is present, but I have no idea how to extract its value from the response object returned by Superagent. I checked the docs but this information is missing.

How do I extract my cookie from this reponse? I can access the string value with `login.req._header` but it contains all the headers and I don't think this is the official way of getting a cookie (with parsing a string value by hand).

Answer (score 0):

All your cookies are stored here

```
login.header['set-cookie']
```

It's a string you can split